# svn create a branch

Tags: svn

I have created a repo called Project however it is a single directory, now I need to create a branch.

So my idea is to create a new repo called Project_prod with directory structure:

- trunk
- branches
- tags

and move repo from Project to Project_prod/trunk is it possible?

Do I have to create (svnadmin create) repos in trunk/branch and than move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be no need to create a new repository to accomplish that.

You can just create the directories "trunk", "branches" and "tags" in the root of your current repository.("svn mkdir" http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re17.html)

Then you move the current content into the trunk directory. ("svn move" http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re18.html)

You can also use any kind of svn explorer to handle the directory creation and movement opperations.